# Configure VSCode to autocomplete from two Python projects

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have read and tried a lot but am still struggeling with correctly configuring IntelliSense, ie, VSCode's autocomplete for my Python projects.

It works fine within a single Python project. But I have a workspace with two of my projects open at the same time since one of them is imported and used inside the other.
For simplicity, let's call them `myProjectA` and `myProjectB`. Inside `myProjectA`, I get  correct autocomplete (incl. suggestions and auto import) for `myProjectA` but not for `myProjectB`, which is used inside A.

How can I configure VSCode to show auto suggestions of `myProjectB` in `myProjectA`?

I have tried adding

```json
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "myProjectB"
    ]
```

to my config, but it doesn't change anything.
Do I need to provide the full path to myProjectB? Or do I need to configure something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it wasn't working for me until i added the path to     "python.analysis.extraPaths" as well:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "path\\to\\directory"
],
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "path\\to\\directory"
]
```

Comment: Yes, ultimately what worked for me was setting both the `extraPaths` in analysis and auto complete + increase the package index depth `"python.analysis.packageIndexDepths"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_enable-intellisense-for-custom-package-locations).

> "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
> "myProjectB"
> ]

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths" This code is for the package, not the workspace.
```

You can use absolute paths, for example, `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/lib/flask-0.12"` to provide intellisense perception for project.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what "This code is for the package, not the workspace." means. How would that refer to a package? More importantly, how can I configure IntelliSense to get what I want? That's my main question; couldn't find it in the docs so far.

Comment: @CGFoX "How would that refer to a package? " If you want to refer to the package, you can use absolute path. This is stated in the docs.

Comment: So I would have to do `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [ "path/to/mycondaenv/myProjectB" ]`? Is `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` the setting I need?
I couldn't find it in the docs and you link goes to GitHub issues...

Comment: @CGFoX, Sorry, this is my omission. I pasted the wrong link, and now I have made changes.

Comment: Hm, autocomplete still does not work for my 2nd project... Somehow I would expect VS Code to automatically support IntelliSense/autocomplete for both project if I have 2 projects open in my workspace.